# How to send content using Netty Http Client?

Tags: httpclient, netty

I'm using Netty Http client to send requests to a http server.

I am re-using the channel and keeping the connection live to reuse it between requests.

My problem is that although the get method works perfectly, I can' manage to send content in put or post. Following is the code I am using but in my server the http request input stream is empty.

Any ideas?

```
HttpRequest request = new DefaultHttpRequest(HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1, HttpMethod.valueOf(method), uri.toASCIIString());
    if (payLoad != null) {
        request.setContent(ChannelBuffers.wrappedBuffer(payLoad));
    }
```

Note: payload is a bytearray.

Thanks,

Yair

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your GET requests work fine, I assume that you write it to channel correctly.

Therefore I would focus on http post:

From http request point of view, you have to specify [few more headers in your request](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields). At the very least have a look at **Host**, **Connection**, **Accept-Encoding**, **Content-Type** and **Content-Length**.

Comment: my bet is on content-length, either that or transport-encoding must be specified as chunked